# android studio does not syncing any github library

Tags: android, android-studio

It's been 3 days that I can't use any library in github , I used to work with most of them but now it doesn't work at all .

it takes about 5 minutes and then I get a message like this :

```
 Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0
<a href="openFile:F:/AndroidStudioProjects/selfi_ramezani/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

here is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
}
```

How can I solve this bothering problem ?

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle file contents please?

Comment: Are you using the offline-mode?

Comment: Yup. Sometimes Offline mode creates problem.

Comment: @Eenvincible I edit my post and add the gradle codes

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti No I'm not in offline mod ,I checked settings

Answer (score 0):

I think Because you are using 2 versions of same library. Use one of them and then build the project.

```
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.2.2'
```

and

```
 compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
```

If you are using a RecyclerView 23.0.1 or below. (As this lib document)

```
dependencies {
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
}
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks...